# I don't see Unity anywhere after upgrading from Kubuntu 10.10 -- what am I missing?

Tags: unity, upgrade, kubuntu

I had Kubuntu 10.10 and had all the updates done there before allowing the upgrade to 11.04. Everything went well insofar as the upgrade. Final reboot and voila! Ummmmm....wait a minute....it looks virtually identical to the Kubuntu screen prior to the upgrade. No "Dock" to the left, etc. Outside of some new default applications, doesn't look like I've done anything.

And I don't see anything on startup asking for default desktop.

OK, and I don't know if this has any bearing -- I'm running this under Windows Vista using VMWare player (most recent version). I've allocated 1 Gig for the virtual OS. And it seems "snappy" enough, all things considered.

Is this just considered too underpowered and THAT'S why Unity isn't visible to me. Is there someplace that I have to make a setting to make it happen. Is there some double secret handshake I need?

Answer (score 4):

You're running Kubuntu, which uses KDE, not Unity, so when you upgraded you got an updated Kubuntu (KDE SC) Desktop, not the GNOME + Compiz based Unity Desktop.

As fossfreedom mentioned you can simply install [unity](http://packages.ubuntu.com/unity) [image: Install unity]. If you want to try it. If you want the Ubuntu styled login, you could install [gdm](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gdm) [image: Install gdm], and when installing, choose gdm as opposed to kdm for your login manager (you will be prompted for a choice).

Comment: installing only the unity package results in a broken system. one needs to install the `ubuntu-desktop` package to get a usable system

Answer (score 3):

You must install unity. Or even better install ubuntu-desktop, with this you get all ubuntu standard packages, as well.

Try in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Kubuntu - you will need to install the Unity Desktop.

Try in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

when this finishes, logout, and choose "Ubuntu" session at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: see comment above

Comment: are you using natty (11.04) version of kubuntu as per the OP?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 desktop types officially supported by ubuntu; Gnome (which uses Unity) http://www.ubuntu.org ; KDE http://www.kubuntu.org ; Xfce http://www.xubuntu.org

Comment: you've forgotten lxde, e17 and a few others... :-)